# WinRt - FileSavePicker, save image from URI to file

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

I would like to ask how I can save image from stream to file. I have created this FileSavePicker, but I don not know how i can save image from Uri

Thanks

```
  StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                // Read the content.
               string responseFromServer = reader.ReadLine(); // URi with image


 private async void saveClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       var Picker = new FileSavePicker();
       Picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Image", new List<string>() { ".jpg" });
       StorageFile file = await Picker.PickSaveFileAsync();



    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you already have downloaded the image into dataStream. If not you can do so with the HttpClient class:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo-med.png");
Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var stream = await httpClient.GetInputStreamAsync(uri);
Stream dataStream = stream.AsStreamForRead();
```

You can get a writeable stream to your picked file by calling OpenStreamForWriteAsync on the StorageFile. With two streams you can call CopyTo to copy from the dataStream to the save stream.

```
var Picker = new FileSavePicker();
Picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Image", new List<string>() { ".jpg" });
StorageFile file = await Picker.PickSaveFileAsync();
using (Stream saveStream = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
{
    dataStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    await dataStream.CopyToAsync(saveStream);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error "Stream does not support seeking."

Comment: That will depend on where your stream comes from. If you're already at the beginning you can just leave out the Seek line